# How does hosted wallets works?

Tags: ether, wallets

How does hosted wallets works, Anyone can write about it step by step?

I have noticed, Companies who provides hosted wallets stores all funds of their users and users are just provided deposit address. And when you check balance of your address then your balance is shown as $0.00 even if you have big amount in your wallet.

Does it work like this? And why our balance is shown as 0.00 in the explorer?

How to setup Ethereum hosted wallet?